# Как отправить header / path / body в формате json с помощью POST curl

Tags: post, curl, request

На данный момент я отправляю только `body` вот такой коммандой :

```
curl -d '{"productId": 0, "pricepointId": 0, "mcc":"string", "mnc":"string", "msisdn":"string", "largeAccount":"string", "entryChannel":"string", "transactionUUID":"string", "text":"string", "tags":["string"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://192.166.0.111/notification/user-optin
```

Как мне добавить `header` и `path` к данной команде, что-бы всё отправлялась одной коммандлй. Буду благодарен любой помощью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методом GET с basic-авторизацией передать `body` в формате `json`

```
curl -i -k -H "Accept:application/json" --user username:password  "https://api.test.server/v1"  -d '{"field1":"string_value", "field2":integer_value, "field3": float.value}'
```

Методом POST c авторизацией через сертификат передать `body` в формате `json`

```
curl -i --cert ./<client>.crt --key ./<client>.key  -k -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" "https://api.test.server/v1" -d '{"field1":"string_value", "field2":integer_value, "field3": float.value}'
```

Методом PATCH передать передать `body` в формате `json`

```
curl -i -k -X PATCH -H "Accept:application/json" "https://api.test.server/v1" -d '{"field1":"string_value", "field2":integer_value, "field3": float.value}'
```

Методом DELETE (например запрос на удаление пользователя с id=7193)

```
curl -i -k -X DELETE -H "Accept:application/json" "https://api.test.server/v1/user/7193"
```